# Can't get how to draw PNG properly via GraphicEx in Delphi

Tags: image, delphi, png, graphicex

I have a little problem with PNG format. To read and display PNG files I use `GraphicEx` library by Mike Lischke ([got it there](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/libs/graphicex-library)). All was good before I decided to draw PNG file with transparent background.
I use this code to load and draw PNG on form's canvas:

```
procedure TForm1.aButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PNGGraph: GraphicEx.TPNGGraphic;
begin
  PNGGraph := GraphicEx.TPNGGraphic.Create;

  PNGGraph.PixelFormat := pf32bit; - added code line

  PNGGraph.LoadFromFile('demo.png');
  Form1.Canvas.Draw(10, 10, PNGGraph);
  PNGGraph.Free;
end;
```

What I get you can see on a picture below:
[image: png without premultiplied alpha]

After hours searching in Internet, I found that I should multiple alpha channel. I get some code from here (Mike Sutton's answer): [Fade in an alpha-blended PNG form in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228820/fade-in-an-alpha-blended-png-form-in-delphi)

```
procedure PreMultiplyBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap);
var
  Row, Col: integer;
  p: PRGBQuad;
  PreMult: array[byte, byte] of byte;
begin
  // precalculate all possible values of a*b
  for Row := 0 to 255 do
    for Col := Row to 255 do
    begin
      PreMult[Row, Col] := Row*Col div 255;
      if (Row <> Col) then
        PreMult[Col, Row] := PreMult[Row, Col]; // a*b = b*a
    end;

  for Row := 0 to Bitmap.Height-1 do
  begin
    Col := Bitmap.Width;
    p := Bitmap.ScanLine[Row];
    while (Col > 0) do
    begin
      p.rgbBlue := PreMult[p.rgbReserved, p.rgbBlue];
      p.rgbGreen := PreMult[p.rgbReserved, p.rgbGreen];
      p.rgbRed := PreMult[p.rgbReserved, p.rgbRed];
      inc(p);
      dec(Col);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Using this code I got a little odd result:
[image]

The picture above has black background and in the same time looks almost as an original image.

On a picture below you can see an original PNGimage:
[image]

So, my question is: how to draw PNG file correctly with transparency and without black background?

I looked into GraphicEx's units, but can't get enough info about my question. Can't believe that such serious graphic library as GraphicEx is not able to draw PNG files without any troubles.

P.S.
Bitmap property Transparent doesn't work properly - black background still on a picture.

Thanks to everyone who can give me advice!

**EDIT**
When I set `PixelFormat = pf32bit`, it makes bitmap 'broken' visually.
Picture below demonstrates this effect:
[image: Artifacts on a bitmap]

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266312/transparent-png-to-tbitmap32) may help

Comment: @fantaghirocco, thank you for link, but that was not helpful. Graphics32 too large for me. GraphicEx seems more elegant. So I still looking for answer on my question.

Comment: Delphi supports PNG out of the box. Why fight with third party libraries unless you need some extra functionality?

Comment: Does the target bitmap have the 32bit RGBA format?

Comment: @David Heffernan, unfortunately, I use Delphi 2005 and I have no abilities to update it. I think GraphicEx is more cheapest way to have a PNG support in this condition.

Comment: @Mike Lischke, if you meant did I set PixelFormat to pf32bit, I did it. But it causes strange artifacts on a bitmap. So the problem is still there.

Comment: You could use pngimage or whatever the library is called

Comment: @David Heffernan, perhaps I will use another libary to get PNG support in applications. But I want to find an answer for my question. It could be helpful for those who stuck with the same trouble as mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Mike's PNG graphic doesn't support drawing transparency.

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
    g: TGraphic;
begin
    g := TPNGGraphic.Create;
    g.LoadFromFile('D:\Temp\FolderOpen_48x48_72.png');
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, g);
end;
```

Comes out without the alpha channel being taken into account:

[image]

### TPNGObject

For Delphi 2005 use can use Gustavo Daud's [pngdelphi](https://github.com/JoseJimeniz/pngdelphi) library (It is the class that was later absorbed into Delphi). It fully supported drawing with alpha blending:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
    g: TGraphic;
begin
//  g := TPNGGraphic.Create;
    g := TPNGObject.Create;
    g.LoadFromFile('D:\Temp\FolderOpen_48x48_72.png');
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, g);
end;
```

It draws correctly:

[image]

### Windows Imaging Component

I don't know when Borland added Windows Imaging Component (WIC) to Delphi. But in Delphi 5 i translated the headers myself, and created a **TGraphic** that uses WIC to perform all the work: `TWicGraphic`:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
    g: TGraphic;
begin
//  g := TPNGGraphic.Create;
//  g := TPNGObject.Create;
    g := TWicGraphic.Create;
    g.LoadFromFile('D:\Temp\FolderOpen_48x48_72.png');
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, g);
end;
```

It also paints correctly:

[image]

### GDI+

There's also GDI+. I also don't know when Borland added support for GDI+ to Delphi. But in Delphi 5 i translated GDI+ myself and created a **TGraphic** that uses GDI+ for all the work, `TGDIPlusGraphic`:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
    g: TGraphic;
begin
//  g := TPNGGraphic.Create;
//  g := TPNGObject.Create;
//  g := TWicGraphic.Create;
    g := TGDIPlusGraphic.Create;
    g.LoadFromFile('D:\Temp\FolderOpen_48x48_72.png');
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, g);
end;
```

it also draws correctly:

[image]

---

But to answer your question: You cannot. Not without re-writing Mike's `TPNGGraphic` to support the alpha channel.

Comment: thank you very much for your contribution! Few days ago I have got PngImage unit and use it to load and display *.png files. Your answer is well illustrated. Suppose it will helpful for others who will come with the same question as mine)